# Displaying Angle Brackets inside TinyMCE Textarea

Tags: html, tinymce

Inside of a TinyMCE text area, I'm trying to place some visible text that will be wrapped by custom html tags. The idea is that whatever a user enters between these custom tags will be handled differently than would text outside of these tags (after I parse the contents of the text area).

When the page loads, I want the user to see *exactly* this inside of the text area (the tags should be visible):

`<my_tag>Some Text</my_tag>`

But what is displaying right now is this:

`Some Text`

I've tried to escape each of the angle brackets so that it will display, but clearly I am doing this wrong. Here is the html code where I am populating the text area:

```
echo "<textarea id='description' rows='20' cols='40'>";
echo "&lt;my_tag&gt;Some Text&lt;/my_tag&gt;";
echo "</textarea>";
```

How can I get this string to display correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Tinymce is a html editor. Even if you assign your custom html tag to the valid_elements you won't see a html tag as a string in a html editor. If you want to see a string in the editor than use a string!

Comment: Thank you. Can you be more specific? How can I display a string that includes substrings that look like an HTML tag, but should not be regarded as such? This approach works correctly outside of the TinyMCE text area, but not inside of it. Is there a way to display a string like this?

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be that tinymce will regard it as a real html elment - and thus treat it as such.

What about this tinymce fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/yZdaab/1

Comment: Thanks for the link to fiddle. I hadn't used that before. It appears to me that what you have done is to add a space inside of the closing tag `< /my_tag>`. This sort of tricks the editor so that it does not interpret the pattern as a pair of html tags. You used `&#47` (the ASCII value for `/`) to generate the `/` but if I just type the `/` directly, I get the exact same behavior. (i.e. If I take out the space and use `&#47`, the closing tag won't display.) So it's clear that what allows the closing tag to display is the space, not the ASCII value encoding. At least the opening tag displays.

Comment: So it seems to me that I need to do something (like what you have done with including a space) so that I vary from the html tag pattern, or else this won't work. Another idea that I had was to use square brackets `[` rather than angle brackets `<`. All I need to do is to somehow mark the text between these tags so that I can handle it differently once the form is submitted.  Thanks for your help. If anyone has any other ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Correct, &#47 or / doesn'T make nay difference. Another thought that came to my mind is to insert a whitespace character that has no or almost no width instead of the space and would make the tag look like you intended to (without getting treated as a real html element by tinymce).